# Assign Special Records for specific remote clients DNSmasq

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq

I'd like to make DNSmasq serve special records for specific remote clients (Clients from the public internet)

So for example if remote host 111.111.111.111 requests www.example.com it returns 3.3.3.3 but if anyone else does it then it will return 4.4.4.4.

Is there any way I can do this using DNSmasq configuration?

I'd prefer not to have to run multiple instances of DNSmasq on my server and use iptables to forward everything to the right one.